# My java code is outputting the incorrect thing, Issue with for loops?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, static-methods

I have looked through every line of my code but I can't find where it goes wrong. There is no error, the output is just wrong, and there is an issue with the math. I'm supposed to create a code where the attacker rolls 3 (20 sided) dice and the defender has 2 (20 sided) dice. Attacker and Defender discards any dice that is higher than the target that was inputted by the user. And then the Attacker discards any dice that are less than or equal to any of the defender dice that are left.

Here's what the output should be (when the user enters 15 and 10):

0 hit(s): 494741

1 hit(s): 1006677

2 hit(s): 1080423

3 hit(s): 618159

And here's what the output is with my code:

0 hit(s): 1020656

1 hit(s): 100373

2 hit(s): 62674

3 hit(s): 16297

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceGame { public static void main(String[] args) { Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numHits = new int[4];
    int attackerTarget, defenderTarget;

    System.out.print("Attacker Target(1-20): ");
    attackerTarget = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Defender Target(1-20): ");
    defenderTarget = input.nextInt();
    
    for (int a = 1; a <= 20; a++) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= 20; b++) { 
            for (int c = 1; c <= 20; c++) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
                        if (i <= attackerTarget && j <= defenderTarget) {
                            int numberOfHits = 0;
                            int attackerNum1 = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
                            int attackerNum2 = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
                            int attackerNum3 = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
                            int defenderNum1 = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
                            int defenderNum2 = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);
                            
                            if (attackerNum1 < attackerTarget && defenderNum1 < defenderTarget && defenderNum2 < defenderTarget) {
                                if (attackerNum1 > defenderNum1 && attackerNum1 > defenderNum2) {
                                    numberOfHits++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (attackerNum2 < attackerTarget && defenderNum1 < defenderTarget && defenderNum2 < defenderTarget) {
                                if (attackerNum2 > defenderNum1 && attackerNum2 > defenderNum2) {
                                    numberOfHits++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (attackerNum3 < attackerTarget && defenderNum1 < defenderTarget && defenderNum2 < defenderTarget) {
                                if (attackerNum3 > defenderNum1 && attackerNum3 > defenderNum2) {
                                    numberOfHits++;
                                }
                            }
                            numHits[numberOfHits]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " hit(s): " + numHits[i]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: How can you say what the output 'should be' when you're using an arbitrarily-initalized random number generator?

Comment: What should I do then? Doesn't Math.random() create a different number everytime?

Comment: Please go into fair detail as to *why* you assume that the output should be as you post above. What logic tells you that this is what you should be seeing? Also, what have you done to debug the code/problem?

Comment: That's my point - you appear to be saying "I expect exactly these numbers as output", but that is not going to happen, because your code is doing random calculations.  Did you mean something else in the original question, like maybe you expect the 1 and 2 hit counts to be largest?

Comment: All the numbers that it outputs should add up to 3,200,000, because 20^5. But they add to 1,200,000. I used 5 for loops that run 20 times but it won't work and I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You do not execute the inner block (the one that ultimately executes `numHits[numberOfHits]++`) on every time through the loop.

You only execute it if `i` and `j` fulfil certain conditions.

```
 if (i <= attackerTarget && j <= defenderTarget) {
     ... lots of code here ...
     numHits[numberOfHits]++;
 }
```

In particular, there's no execution if `i >= 15` or `j >= 10` given the stated inputs.

So nothing is counted in those cases, which account for more than half of the 3,200,000 loops.

Comment: You're right, but the output still doesn't equal the correct outputs for each hit count. My friend is challenging me to create a code that outputs that so that's why I know that that has to be the output.

Comment: You'll get different outputs each time you run it.  Because "random".  If you want repeatable results, you need to use a [random number generator you can initialize to a particular starting point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random-long-).  However, guessing the right starting point for those particular numbers is nigh-on impossible.

Comment: but it gives me the same output everytime with the Math.random()  's

Comment: That seems very strange, since Math.random() does not repeat the same sequence on repeated runs.  (Try writing a program where 'main' is just a single call to print Math.random(), you'll see it's different on every run).

Answer (score 0):

## Minor Code Review

First, I have a few notes on your overall code.

1. Your code is difficult to follow because of all the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20a%20magic,see%20List%20of%20file%20signatures).  You should make better use of constants in your code so that it's easier to read.  For example, instead of `int attackerNum1 = (int) (Math.random() * 20 + 1);` you can do `int attackerNum1 = (int) (Math.random() * DICE_SIZE + 1);` where `DIE_SIZE = 20`.  This eliminates confusion when you have a loop that is `for (int a = 1; a <= 20; a++) {`, I can't tell on first glance if that 20 used there is because of the size of the die, or just some arbitrary magic number.
2. Your loops are also arbitray.  You are nesting loops in loops for no reason.  If you're not going to use the value of `a`, `b`, or `c`, there's no difference between what you have and `for (int i = 0; i <= Math.pow(20, 5); a++)`.  Limiting the number of loops makes your code much more readable.
3. Try to limit duplicate code.  All of your random die rolls and your conditional checks are duplicate code.  You should extract these into their own  methods.
4. Finally, limit the amount of work you do in `main`.  This can all be extracted into its own method to support reusability.

## The Code

So, keeping all the above tips in mind, I rewrote your code as follows.

#### Main

```java
public class MainClass
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Attacker Target(1-20): ");
    int attackerTarget = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Defender Target(1-20): ");
    int defenderTarget = input.nextInt();

    DiceGame game = new DiceGame(attackerTarget, defenderTarget);

    game.playGame();
  }
}
```

#### DiceGame

```java
public class DiceGame
{
  private static final int DICE_SIZE = 20;
  private static final int GAMES = (int) Math.pow(DICE_SIZE, 5);
  private static final int NUMBER_OF_ATTACKER_DIE = 3;
  private static final int NUMBER_OF_DEFENDER_DIE = 2;
  private final int[] numberOfHits = new int[NUMBER_OF_ATTACKER_DIE + 1];
  private final int attackerTarget;
  private final int defenderTarget;

  public DiceGame(int attackerTarget, int defenderTarget)
  {
    this.attackerTarget = attackerTarget;
    this.defenderTarget = defenderTarget;
  }

  public void playGame()
  {
    int[][] attackerRolls = new int[GAMES][NUMBER_OF_ATTACKER_DIE];
    int[][] defenderRolls = new int[GAMES][NUMBER_OF_DEFENDER_DIE];

    System.out.println("Playing " + GAMES + " games.");
    // play the games.
    for (int i = 0; i < GAMES; i++) {
      // roll the attacker die for this game
      for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_ATTACKER_DIE; j++) {
        int randRoll = rollDie();
        // only take the attacker die if it is less than or equal to the user provided value for attackerTarget
        // otherwise places value outside expected range
        attackerRolls[i][j] = randRoll <= getAttackerTarget() ? randRoll : -1;
      }
      // roll the defender die for this game
      for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_DEFENDER_DIE; j++) {
        int randRoll = rollDie();
        // only take the defender die if it is less than or equal to the user provided value for defenderTarget
        // otherwise places value outside expected range
        defenderRolls[i][j] = randRoll <= getDefenderTarget() ? randRoll : DICE_SIZE + 1;
      }

      // checks all defender die, filters by only numbers within the expected range, and then returns the lowest number
      int defMax = IntStream.of(defenderRolls[i]).filter(this::valInRange).max().orElse(0);

      // returns the number of attacker die that are greater than the biggest defender die
      int winningAttacks = (int) (IntStream.of(attackerRolls[i]).filter(v -> v > defMax).count());

      numberOfHits[winningAttacks]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      System.out.println(i + " hit(s): " + numberOfHits[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Total Games Played: " + IntStream.of(numberOfHits).sum());
  }

  private boolean valInRange(int val)
  {
    return val > 0 && val <= DICE_SIZE;
  }

  public int rollDie()
  {
    return (int) (Math.random() * DICE_SIZE) + 1;
  }

  public int getAttackerTarget()
  {
    return attackerTarget;
  }

  public int getDefenderTarget()
  {
    return defenderTarget;
  }
}
```

## A Few Notes on the rules and optimization

The rules appear to be as follows:

1. The attacker and the defender have a max possible roll, as defined by the user input.  You could potentially change the size of the dice available to be a max of that number.  This would eliminate the need to check if the resulting value is outside of the range.  However, this could have the unwanted desire of making every roll a valid roll.
2. When you say "the Attacker discards any dice that are less than or equal to any of the defender dice that are left", this is difficult to translate in to code.  For example, if the defender has 2 dice rolls of 10 and 15, and the attacker rolls a 12, is this discarded or kept? Based on your code, you kept the number if it was greater than both of the defender's dice roll.  So, I only compared the number to the max.  But your rules may be different than your code.
3. You could study the [Monte Carlo Simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) to see various ways you could tweak and optimize your code.  This simulation is used to model the probability of different outcomes in a process that cannot easily be predicted due to the intervention of random variables. It is a technique used to understand the impact of risk and uncertainty.  The scholarly paper ["A Survey of Monte-Carlo Techniques in Games"](https://www.cs.umd.edu/sites/default/files/scholarly_papers/Rajkumar_1.pdf) covers various ways this is used in board games and ["RAWR: Algorithm for Dungeons and Dragons Strategy Optimization"](https://web.stanford.edu/class/aa228/reports/2020/final98.pdf) covers its use specifically in Dungeons and Dragons.